# Unable to run QT in Netbeans IDE (able to build) "QtCored4.dll was not found"

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans

I'm new to QT in netbeans and i followed the tutorial as shown here :
https://netbeans.org/kb/72/cnd/qt-applications.html

My C++ Tools->Options->C++ build is as shown below 
[image]

The PATH included that shows the required files :
[image]
I followed ALL the steps indicated in the Netbeans tutorial.
Currently running QT SDK 4.8.1(only version i can find on the web).
When i run the program , it build O.K but was unable to run with Run failed

```
The application failed with exit code -1073741515 (0xc0000135). 
This could indicate that no required .dll was found in the PATH.
```

I tried pasting the .dll found within my C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin inside the directory of my application but it still doesnt work. Could anybody help me out please?

Thank you !

Comment: Do you have the Qt bin folder in your system path? I assume you can also set this in debugging options tab although I have not used netbeans.

Comment: i found that missing file in some other folder and i tried including those file path into the code inclusion directory. but the problem is still persistent. See updated question for the screenshot

Comment: This should not be in a code inclusion folder. It has nothing to do with building. Its about running your application. I would expect execution settings to be in the Debugging Options tab.

Comment: And if there is not a setting for that in the Debugging Options tab then set your path in windows (if you have administration privileges).

Comment: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Comment: After setting  the path close netbeans and restart it.